# Validating a check box using jquery and displaying custom alert

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all I am having two check-boxes and a button on my form

I use the below on to alert the custom alerts as per my need

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkArray" runat="server" Text="Check Me" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkArray1" runat="server" Text="Check Me" />
<p>
  <asp:button id="btnDelete" text="Show Alert"/>
</p>
</form>
```

I have written the script to find out whether check box are checked or not as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var flag = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
                if (rbs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                    if (rbs[i].checked) {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0) {
                alert('msg');
                //var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('#checkArray :checkbox:checked').length > 0;

                //if (atLeastOneIsChecked == 0) {
                jAlert('Select One', 'Alert Dialog');

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

But I am unable to see the required alert. Where as the below one works perfectly

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <fieldset id="checkArray">
        <div>
            <input name="list" id="list0" type="checkbox" value="newsletter0">zero</div>
        <div>
            <input name="list" id="list1" type="checkbox" value="newsletter1">one</div>
        <div>
            <input name="list" id="list2" type="checkbox" value="newsletter2">two</div>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Show Alert" />
    </p>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
            var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('#checkArray :checkbox:checked').length > 0;

            if (atLeastOneIsChecked == 0) {
                jAlert('Select One', 'Alert Dialog');

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Now to work this out the same using asp.net controls where should I change can any one help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I solved it adding false to the script works well for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
             var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('#checkArray :checkbox:checked').length > 0;

             if (atLeastOneIsChecked == 0) {
                 jAlert('Select One', 'Alert Dialog');

             }
             else {
                 $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
                     var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('#checkArray :checkbox:checked').length > 0;

                     if (atLeastOneIsChecked == 0) {
                         jAlert('Select One', 'Alert Dialog');
                         //return false;
                     }
                     else {
                         jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog');
                         //return false;
                     }

                 });
             }
             return false;
         });

     });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are saving the checkboxes in `input`:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

but looping through `rbs`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
```

It would be wise to use jQuery for this task, if you use it on the site. I’m pretty sure you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $('#form1');
    $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
        if ( !form.find(':checkbox:checked').length ) {
            jAlert('Select One', 'Alert Dialog');
        }
    });
});
```

... in your ASP form.

Comment: Hi but the alert message is getting displayed and off in a flash

Comment: Even though I use `inputs` I can not get that alert

Comment: If the alert flashes, it is not related to the code above. Here is a proof of concept, use it as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/W3kpM/